# jToolBar menu that follow the horizontal size dimension of the main jFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a `JToolBar` that has to resize it's horizontal length following the main `JFrame`.
If in the `JFrame` I don't set any `JPanel` all goes well, but if I add a `JPanel` into the `JFrame` and I resize the `JFrame`, the length of the `JToolBar` doesn't change.

How i can "anchor" permanently the horizontal length of the `JToolBar` to the length of the `JFrame`?

I have the same problem with a `JTable` that seems to be anchored to the `JPanel` and not to the main `JFrame`...

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: You need to use `LayoutManager`

Comment: Can you provide ad example? I'm using the window builder of netbeans so i have a lot of code "blocked" and "autoegenerated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). There are lot of layouts and you have to choose one that match to your requirements.

First, add layout to the `JPanel`.
Then, add `JToolBar` to the `JPanel` position that you want(depend on layout that you choose).

As a example, if you choose [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html):

You can position component in rows and cells(More flexible).

Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

public class Grid {

    public Grid(){
          execute();
    }

    public void execute(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBag");
        frame.setSize(400,400);

        JPanel panel= new JPanel();

        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.setRollover(true);
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        panel.setLayout(layout);        
        panel.setSize(300,300);

        GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Hey");
        label2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        label2.setOpaque(true);
        JButton button = new JButton("Say");

        constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraint.gridx = 0;
        constraint.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(label, constraint);

        constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        constraint.gridx = 2;
        constraint.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(label2, constraint);

        constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraint.gridx = 0;
        constraint.gridy = 1;
        toolbar.add(button);
        toolbar.addSeparator();

        panel.add(toolbar, constraint);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        pane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Grid g = new Grid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the layout manager of the content pane of the frame is a `BorderLayout`. So typically you add the toolbar to the frame using `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` as the constraint for the `BorderLayout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Toolbars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for a working example.